# Alias for checking if folders in one directory exist in another

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I'm trying to create an alias that will check if all of the folders in one directory are also in another directory and if not, tell me which ones aren't.

This is what I'm trying:

```
alias files_not="for i in var=$(ls -1 ~/Desktop/x/storage | tr '\n' ' ');do if [ ! -d ~/Documents/x/files/${i} ];then echo '${i} files not converted';fi;done"
```

Help on getting this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be fairly easily adapted into an alias:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /path/to/dir1/*; do
    basefile=${file##*/}
    if ! [[ -f "/path/to/dir2/$basefile" ]]; then
        echo "$basefile is not present in target location."
    fi
done
```

Comment: oh hmmm, are you saying create a script and have the alias call the script?

Comment: Rather make a function than an alias.

Comment: you can make that into a script and have the alias call the script yes, that's what I always do. Alternatively you can put the executable in /usr/local/bin/ or /usr/local/sbin/ which exists pretty much for user created scripts and applications to be placed in them. That way you don't need to even make an alias.

Comment: Or even `$HOME/bin` (:

Comment: @DopeGhoti what does the `##*` do in this case?

Comment: `${variable##*/}` is a form of substring manipulation.  What it does is remove the largest match of `*/` from the start of the string; it turns `/path/to/dir1/file.ext` into `file.ext`.